# using Drupal for 1 page of xhtml-css website

Tags: php, drupal, xhtml, .htaccess, content-management-system

after using own custom cms for over 6 years, I decided to go for Drupal from now on. I will use Drupal for all my works. I'm pretty new at Drupal, started just 2 days ago :D

just a simple question;
I have a simple xhtml-css site (5 pages), and client is asking cms for gallery page (xhtml for now). so is it possible to make only 1 page with drupal and rest pages are using current xhtml somehow? How would I create the base with Drupal for such custom (out of Drupal) pages' links? or do I have to transfer all other html pages into Drupal as Page (drupal page)?

*ps, as a new drupal user, i didnt see anything complicated as everybody complains, it is pretty well structured-clear... love it so far :) ps, i say 2 days but I had only few hours so far :)*

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Drupal URL rewriting rules only apply to *files and directories that do not exist on the file system*, so as long as you avoid naming conflicts, you can put 'static' pages more or less anywhere you like, and Drupal will not interfere with them being served.

That said, it would probably be a good idea to consolidate them within a 'static' folder, either on the top level of the document root, or (more appropriate) within the 'sites' or the 'files' folder of the new Drupal install (which implies adjusting your current paths).

However, I agree with Kevin (+1) that for only 5 pages, it is probably less work in the long run to 'migrate' them to Drupal right from the start, as you will save work and trouble down the road as soon as you further enhance the site.

Comment: hmm, if I would have to move the static files under a static folder, it sounds much sensible to migrate static pages to Drupal. ps, I don't think migrating would be time-taking as xhtml-css are are ready for each page, so all I will do is, copy and paste to Page (Drupal created page). easy... am I wrong?

Comment: Right. You would copy the content of the page into Drupal, and take the xhtml structure and css and make it into a theme. You can also adapt the Framework or Zen theme on drupal.org to work with your markup.

Comment: yeah i have tried Zen Theme, thats cool, fresh-clean start! :) love it!

Answer (score 2):

If its only 5 pages, why not put it all into Drupal? Less overhead that way. Otherwise you will have to edit .htaccess, manually update files instead of making simple changes in Drupal, and edit multiple files should the theme change in any way.

If you need a Gallery solution, I would suggest checking out the Gallery Assist module.

Comment: wow Kevin, again you :) you are very supportive about Drupal questions! thanks a lot, appreciate! So you advise to trans pages to Drupal, okay thanks. ps, I have an another project which has over 30 static xhtml-css pages, and client is asking for a job-bulletin, I will develop with Drupal (good one to see what i can do with drupal :) . for such big scope, i guess i better find a different solution rather than transfering all to Drupal. so you say, I can take control via .htaccess redirections? hmm, i will think over it. thanks! ps im gonna see Gallery Assist module ;)

Comment: Doesn't sound like such a big scope. Once you dig into Drupal you will find it is capable of a whole lot. Look for modules that have node expiration capabilities, and then a job posting is nothing more than a custom node type with CCK fields that has an unpublish date. Many ways to approach that :D

Answer (score 0):

If all 5 pages use the same or similar layouts, navigation, etc then it makes the most sense to put them all in Drupal.

Setting up, configuring, and theming Drupal will be a lot more effort than one page is worth.

But if all your content does not share a similar layout and have very different looks then you may consider leaving them static.

There are many ways to vary the the layout, navigaiton, and such within Drupal, but this may be a challenge for a Drupal beginner and even require a substantial effort from Drupal pros.

If you leave content external to Drupal that includes identical layout elements, it leads to redundant work.